# Why are positive and negative variations (positive) measures?

Tags: measure-theory

According to Rudin's textbook, if $\mu$ is a signed measure , we define

$$\mu^+ = \frac{1}{2}(|\mu|+\mu)$$
and
$$\mu^-=\frac{1}{2}(|\mu|-\mu).$$

(the positive and negative varitions resp.) , with $$|\mu|(E)=\sup \sum_i |\mu(E_i)|, $$ where the supremum is taken over all countable partitions of $E$.

The countable additivity is easy to see but I can't see why $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ take positive (real) values.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because $|\mu|(E) \geq \left | \sum \mu(E_i) \right |=|\mu(E)|$ by the triangle inequality and countable additivity of $\mu$.